# The mapping $\theta : S^{-1}R \rightarrow (\pi(S))^{-1}(R/I)$ is a well-defined ring epimorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working on this problem for a homework assignment. Note that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, $I$ is an ideal of $R$, and $\pi : R \to R/I$ is the canonical projection given by $\pi(r)=r+I$.

I have no problem showing that $\theta$ is an epimorphism (surjective homomorphism), but I'm really struggling to show that the map is well-defined. Since elements of $S^{-1}R$ are unique up to an equivalence relation, I need to show that the representative I choose does not affect the image of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [universal property of the localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring#Universal_property). (*Never* use the explicit construction of the localization unless you want to do long calculations.)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the universal property of the localization?

Comment: @kayeomans: I've added a wikipedia link.

Comment: @Pedro: Not now, please send me an e-mail instead.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this property and using the construction to show that $\theta$ is well-defined. I'm looking for something more explicit. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

To show the mapping is well-defined.

Pick 2 elements in $ R $ assume $ x, y $.

Assume they are equal.[ Is $x-y$ in $ R ?$ why ?]

We want show the image of these elements are equal.

Show that $ x+I= y+I $ in $ R/l $.

If you show that then you done.